# Prove multiplicative inverses in reduced residue system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

The [RSA paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf), states:

> Since $d$ is relatively prime to $φ(n)$, it has a multiplicative inverse $e$ in the ring of integers modulo $φ(n)$

This quote presumes that every element in a reduced residue system (modulo n) has a multiplicative inverse (modulo n). Could you please help me prove this fact or provide some intuition?

Beginner-friendly please (preferably no abstract algebra).

Comment: every element _relatively prime_ to **$\varphi(n)$** has a multiplicative inverse modulo **$\varphi(n)$**; cf. [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Comment: $\,q := d\,$ is coprime to  $\,a := \phi(n)\,$ so by the dupe $\,q\,$ is invertible $\bmod a,\,$ i.e.  $\,d\,$ is invertible $\bmod \phi(n),\,$ exactly what is claimed.